# How to fetch datatype , constraints(pk,fk) from table in a database and save it

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I have one Business(Database) where there is 20 tables and I need to fetch all the column name with the data type and table constraint(PK and FK ) only in both SQL and Oracle server and save it in a csv for analysis .
SQL Server :

```sql
SELECT TABLE_CATALOG,TABLE_SCHEMA,TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

Oracle :

```
describe <table_name>
```

Not sure how to fetch it once for the database fetching all table in one go instead of putting one table at a time

Comment: Cross site dupe candidate: [Information_Schema on oracle?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/224083/140734)

Comment: Use the same query as the linked duplicate, just also fetch the `owner`, `table_name` and `data_type` columns (or use `*` to get all the columns from that data dictionary table).